# DotNet Date/Time Error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my application I'm getting the below error I don't know to how to handle or solve it. Can any one help me to overcome the error.
My-Code:

```
private string GetJsonSerializeObject(Object obj)
        {
            var converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" };

            var jSonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Converters = new List<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter> { converter }
            };

            String sobj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, jSonSettings);

            return sobj;
        }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect us to do without code?

Comment: Can you post the code which gives you this error?

Comment: `com.cex.persistence.User` looks like a Java namespace - are you sure this isn't a Java app that is throwing the error?  I've never seen the .NET framework refer to itself as "DotNet".  Do you have access to the source code for the application?  If you don't, you'll need to contact the author or vendor.

Comment: off topic without code. Note that format tries to be ISO8601, but fails due to use of `.` instead of `:`.

Comment: please check my code..it works good on other machines but unable to work in my machine..

Comment: Thanx for you help friends.. there is no mistake with my code.. I had adjusted the System DateTime Settings.. this error has be corrected.. Thank-You for Your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx for you help friends.. there is no mistake with my code.. I had adjusted the System DateTime Settings.. this error has be corrected.. Thank-You for Your Help